# PHP to detect and convert Special Characters?

Tags: php, unicode, hex, ascii, special-characters

In PHP when i read the Data, let say the data (chunks of strings) is containing HTML Special Character DECIMAL HEX Codes like:
`This is a sample string with &#x153; and &#x161;`

We can say above HEX codes are the source codes of its correspondence Symbol and these will be rendered as correct Symbols in Browser.

But what i want to do is, for these characters (for example), i want these HEX(es) as the converted original Character Symbols like:
`This is a sample string with œ and š`

So how can i **detect the any of decimal HEX Codes inside a string and convert each of them into final Symbol(s)**, instead of keeping HEX codes?

Note:
For more clearence, is there any function to **detect and convert** the Hex to Symbol?
Like:
`&#x153;` => `œ`
`&#x161;` => `š`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$s = "This is a sample string with &#x153; and &#x161;";
echo html_entity_decode($s, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: this does not work! Browser output: <pre>This is a sample string with &#x153; and &#x161;</pre>

Comment: @JvdBerg Probably because you output isn’t declared to be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: run this from the console not on a browser, the question said nothing about browsers what you care about is that the result of html_entity_decode will hold the UTF-8 representation of this characters

Answer (score 1):

Those are HTML entities - you can go back to actual symbol with [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Comment: This does not work!! browser output: <pre>This is a sample string with &#x153; and &#x161;</pre>

Comment: No, actually those are [character references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136750/php-unicode-character-questions/5136787#5136787). An entity reference would be `&amp;` that refers to the entity *amp* that represents `&#38;`.

Answer (score -1):

make sure anything you use (database tables, json or xml for data exchange, html files etc etc etc) is in UTF-8 format