# PHP to Detect and Split Out html Special Character Codes in a String?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, hex, special-characters

In PHP when i read the Data, lets say the data (chunk of string) is containing HTML Special Character DECIMAL HEX Codes like:
`This is a sample string with &lt; &#x153; &lt; and &#x161;`

What i want is, **how to Detect and Split out the Decimal Hex Codes** (of any Special Characters) inside a chunk of string?

For example, above string contains:

- Two Count of `&lt;`
- One Count of `&#x153;`
- One Count of `&#x161;`

How can i programatically detect it (The OCCURRENCE for any Html Special Characters)?
*(Collected results will be better as an Array)*

Comment: What about [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334022/php-to-detect-and-convert-special-characters)?

Comment: Hi @Gumbo, do you find any clue about duplication here?

Comment: Well, after your fourth edit not much any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
$s = 'This is a sample string with &#x153; and &#x161;';

$pattern = '/\&#x\d+\;/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $s, $matches);   

var_dump( $matches );
```

This will output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "&#x153;"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "&#x161;"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i modified my question by adding more basic html character patterns.

Comment: You could change the pattern for that. But I think you want to replace, so have a look at preg_replace.

Comment: I think it would we wise to formulate your question right, and not change is 4 timers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use preg_match() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php with pattern like this '/&[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,5};/g'.

[Updated]: Note what entities you need. Is that just `&#x[number][number][number];` or all possible html-entities (like `&nbsp;`, `&lt;` e.t.c.)?

Above I described the most common case.

Comment: Actually, for all possible html-entities.

Comment: Sorry, i modified my question by adding more basic html character patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You could use substr and strpos to find `&#` and skip to the next `;`:

```
$string = "This is a sample string with &#x153; and &#x161;"
$hexCodes = array();
while (strlen($string) > 0) {
  if (strpos("&#") > 0) {
    $string = substr($string, strpos("&#"));
    $hex = substr($string, 0, strpos(";") + 1);
    $string = substr($string, strpos(";") + 1);
    array_push($hexCodes, $hex);
  } 
  else { break; }
}
```

Comment: preg_match_all is probably more elegant. This is the "hard" way ;-)

Answer (score -2):

If you mean to decode the entities, use html_entity_decode. 
Here is an example:

```
<?php
$a = "I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt;";

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
?>
```

Comment: No, so how do you KNOW/DETECT you've gotten 2x `&quot;` and 2x `&lt;` and 2x `&gt;` having inside your string??

Comment: This function decodes EVERY occurrence of HTML entities. You don't need to know how many times it appears.

Comment: Humm??? How you tell `i don't need to know` ???? So how will you COUNT when you need to know the counts???? Strange answer!

Comment: @4lvin I mentioned in the post itself that if you meant to only decode then use this. 
If you want to count the occurences, I think you will need to create an array of all the html entities and search for each of them in the given text. This would be a time consuming process but i cant think of any other approach right now